# How to use a getter in a class for multiple class without instantiation

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to instantiate a class and use a getters for multiple class without instantiation.

For example:
If user can be logged , I would to instantiate a class

```
new MyClass(aParameter)
```

The user can be navigate for multiple view, and during the navigation I would like to use a getter

```
String get ParamUser => user;
```

I show my example class

```
class MyClass {
  String param;

  MyClass(String el) {
    this.param = el;
  }
  String get ParamUser => param;
  set setparam(String ParamUser ) => param = ParamUser ;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem, I don't know why i can the getter without instantiate in the class.   I can instiate in the class but how i can get the value without instantiate  in the other class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make everything in your class `static`:

```dart
class MyClass {
  static String param;

  static String get ParamUser => param;
  static set setparam(String ParamUser) => param = ParamUser ;
}
```

Then access elements with static access syntax e.g. `MyClass.ParamUser`